# Parse Xml to a local file and show it to recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Help me with this code.  I'm parsing the xml file, add the object to the ArrayList, and then display the information in recyclerview, but only one object is displayed although ArrayList contains 5 objects. How do I display all objects? Thank you. Here is my code

```
public class WorldRegionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorldRegionsAdapter.WorldRegionsHolder> {

private static final String TAG = WorldRegionsAdapter.class.getCanonicalName();
public List<WorldRegion> worldRegionList;
private Context context;

public WorldRegionsAdapter(Context context, List<WorldRegion> worldRegionList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.worldRegionList = worldRegionList;
}

@Override
public WorldRegionsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.world_region, viewGroup, false);
    return new WorldRegionsHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WorldRegionsHolder worldRegionsHolder, int position) {
    WorldRegion worldRegion = worldRegionList.get(position);
    worldRegionsHolder.ivWorld.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_world_globe_dark);
    worldRegionsHolder.tvRegion.setText(worldRegion.getRegionName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return worldRegionList.size();
}

public static class WorldRegionsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.iv_world_globe)
    ImageView ivWorld;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_region)
    TextView tvRegion;

    public WorldRegionsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class WorldRegion {

public String polyExtract;
public String regionType;
public String regionName;

public WorldRegion() {
}

public WorldRegion(String region, String regionType, String regionName) {
    this.polyExtract = region;
    this.regionType = regionType;
    this.regionName = regionName;
}

public String getPolyExtract() {
    return polyExtract;
}

public void setPolyExtract(String polyExtract) {
    this.polyExtract = polyExtract;
}

public String getRegionType() {
    return regionType;
}

public void setRegionType(String regionType) {
    this.regionType = regionType;
}

public String getRegionName() {
    return regionName;
}

public void setRegionName(String regionName) {
    this.regionName = regionName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WorldRegion{" +
            "polyExtract='" + polyExtract + '\'' +
            ", regionType='" + regionType + '\'' +
            ", regionName='" + regionName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
public class DownloadMapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String FREE_DEVICE_MEMORY = "Free ";
private WorldRegionsAdapter adapter;
private List<WorldRegion> worldRegionList;

// All static variables
static final String KEY_URL = "https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources/blob/master/countries-info/regions.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TYPE = "type"; // parent node
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_POLY_EXTRACT = "poly_extract";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_maps);

    TextView tvMemory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_free_memory);
    String devMemory = DeviceMemory.getTotalInternalMemorySize();
    tvMemory.setText(FREE_DEVICE_MEMORY + devMemory);

    ProgressBar pbMemory = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_memory);
    pbMemory.setScaleY(3f);
    int numDevMemory = Integer.parseInt(devMemory.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    pbMemory.setProgress(numDevMemory);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources/blob/master/countries-info/regions.xml");
    File getFileName = new File("" + uri);
    getFileName.getName();

    worldRegionList = new ArrayList<>();
    WorldRegion worldRegion = new WorldRegion();

    RecyclerView rvWorldRegions = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_world_regions);

    rvWorldRegions.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    WorldRegionsAdapter adapter = new WorldRegionsAdapter(this, worldRegionList);
    rvWorldRegions.setAdapter(adapter);
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.contacts);
        String name = null;
        while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equals("region")) {
                if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type").equalsIgnoreCase("continent")) {
                name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                worldRegion.setRegionName(name);
                worldRegionList.add(worldRegion);
                }
            }
            parser.next();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    }
}
```

}

and my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <!-- north-europe -->
    <region name="denmark" lang="da" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
    <region name="estonia" lang="et" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
    <region name="iceland" lang="is" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
    <region name="faroe-islands" translate="Faroe Islands;entity=node" lang="fo" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
    <region name="finland" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="fi,sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
        <region map="no" name="aland" translate="name:fi=Ahvenanmaa;admin_level=3;entity=relation"/>
        <region type="srtm" name="eastern-finland" translate="Eastern Finland;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="northern-finland" map="no" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northern Finland;entity=relation" boundary="no">
            <region type="srtm" name="lapland" translate="Lapland;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="northern-ostrobothnia" translate="name:en=Northern Ostrobothnia;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region type="srtm" name="southern-finland" translate="Southern Finland;entity=relation"/>
        <region type="srtm" name="western-finland" translate="Western Finland;entity=relation"/>
    </region>
    <region name="latvia" lang="lv" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
    <region name="lithuania" lang="lt" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
    <region name="norway" srtm="no" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="nb,nn" poly_extract="north-europe" join_map_files="yes">
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="akershus"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="astfold" translate="Østfold;entity=node"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="aust-agder"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="buskerud"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="finnmark"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hedmark"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hordaland"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="more-og-romsdal" translate="Møre og Romsdal;entity=node"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nordland"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nord-trondelag" translate="Nord-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oppland"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oslo"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="rogaland"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sogn-og-fjordane" translate="Sogn og Fjordane;entity=node"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sor-trondelag" translate="Sør-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="telemark"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="troms"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vest-agder"/>
        <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vestfold"/>
        <region name="svalbard-and-jan-mayen" translate="Svalbard;entity=relation"/>
    </region>
    <region name="sweden" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="blekinge" translate="Blekinge län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="dalarna" translate="Dalecarlia;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gavleborg" translate="Gävleborgs län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gotland" translate="Gotlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="halland" translate="Hallands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jamtland" translate="Jämtlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jonkoping" translate="Jönköpings län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kalmar" translate="Kalmar län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kronoberg" translate="Kronobergs län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="norrbotten" translate="Norrbottens län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="orebro" translate="Örebro län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="ostergotland" translate="Östergötlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="skane" translate="Skåne län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sodermanland" translate="Södermanlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="stockholm" translate="Stockholms län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="uppsala" translate="Uppsala län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="varmland" translate="Värmlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasterbotten" translate="Västerbottens län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasternorrland" translate="Västernorrlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastmanland" translate="Västmanlands län;entity=relation"/>
        <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastra-gotaland" translate="Västra Götalands län;entity=relation"/>
    </region>

    <!-- east-europe -->
    <region name="belarus" lang="be,ru" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="bulgaria" lang="bg" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="czech-republic" inner_download_prefix="$name" translate="Czech Republic;entity=node" lang="cs,sk" poly_extract="east-europe" join_map_files="yes">
        <region name="jihovychod" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Southeast;ref=CZ06;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="jihozapad" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Southwest;ref=CZ03;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="moravskoslezsko" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Moravia-Silesia;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="praha" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Prague;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="severovychod" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northeast;ref=CZ05;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="severozapad" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northwest;ref=CZ04;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="stredni-cechy" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Central Bohemia;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="stredni-morava" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Central Moravia;entity=relation"/>
    </region>
    <region name="hungary" lang="hu" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="moldova" lang="ro" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="poland" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="pl" poly_extract="east-europe" join_map_files="yes">
        <region name="greater-poland" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Greater Poland;entity=node"/>
        <region name="kuyavian-pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Kuyavian-Pomerania;entity=node"/>
        <region name="lesser-poland" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Lesser Poland;entity=node"/>
        <region name="lodz" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Łódź;entity=node"/>
        <region name="lower-silesian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Lower Silesia;entity=node"/>
        <region name="lublin" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Lublin Voivodeship;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="lubusz" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no"/>
        <region name="masovian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Masovia;entity=node"/>
        <region name="opole" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Opole Voivodeship;entity=node"/>
        <region name="podlachian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Podlachia;entity=node"/>
        <region name="pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Pomerania;entity=node"/>
        <region name="silesian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Silesia;entity=node"/>
        <region name="subcarpathian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Subcarpathia;entity=node"/>
        <region name="swietokrzyskie" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Holy Cross;entity=node"/>
        <region name="warmian-masurian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Warmian-Masurian Voivodeship;entity=node"/>
        <region name="west-pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="West Pomerania;entity=node"/>
    </region>
    <region name="romania" lang="ro" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="slovakia" lang="sk" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="transnistria" hillshade="no" lang="ru,uk,ro" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
    <region name="ukraine" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="uk,ru" poly_extract="east-europe">
        <region name="cherkasy" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Cherkasy Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="chernihiv" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Chernihiv Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="chernivtsi" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Chernivtsi Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="crimea" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" boundary="ukraine/crimea" translate="name:en=Autonomous Republic of Crimea;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="dnipropetrovsk" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Dnipropetrovsk Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="donetsk" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Donetsk Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="ivano-frankivsk" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Ivano-Frankivsk Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="kharkiv" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Kharkiv Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="kherson" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Kherson Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="khmelnytskyy" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Khmelnytskyi Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="kiev" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Kyiv Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="kiev-city" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Kyiv;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="kirovohrad" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Kirovohrad Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="luhansk" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Luhansk Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="lviv" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Lviv Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="mykolayiv" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Mykolaiv Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="odessa" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Odessa Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="poltava" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Poltava Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="rivne" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Rivne Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="sumy" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Sumy Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="ternopil" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Ternopil Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="transcarpathia" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Zakarpattia Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="vinnytsya" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Vinnytsia Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="volyn" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Volyn Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="zaporizhzhya" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Zaporizhia Oblast;entity=relation"/>
        <region name="zhytomyr" hillshade="no" srtm="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Zhytomyr Oblast;entity=relation"/>
    </region>

    <!-- south-europe -->
    <region name="albania" lang="sq" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="andorra" lang="ca" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="azores" translate="Azores;entity=relation" hillshade="no" lang="pt" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="bosnia-herzegovina" translate="Bosnia and Herzegovina;entity=node" lang="bs,hr,sr" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="croatia" lang="hr" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="cyprus" translate="name:en=Cyprus;entity=node" lang="el,tr" left_hand_navigation="yes" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="greece" lang="el" poly_extract="south-europe"/>
    <region name="italy" map="no" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="it" poly_extract="south-europe" join_road_files="yes">
        <region name="abruzzo" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="basilicata" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="calabria" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="campania" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="emilia-romagna" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="friuli-venezia-giulia" translate="Friuli Venezia Giulia;entity=node" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="lazio" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="liguria" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="lombardia" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="marche" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="molise" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="piemonte" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="puglia" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="sardegna" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="sicilia" hillshade="no" />
        <region name="toscana" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="trentino-alto-adige" translate="Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol;entity=node" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="umbria" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="valle-aosta" translate="Valle d'Aosta;entity=node" hillshade="no"/>
        <region name="veneto" hillshade="no"/>
    </region>
```

Comment: please debug your code in the while loop and see if its working properly

Comment: I'm debugging. The size counted but did not show in recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . set adapter after putting objects in arraylist

```
try {
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.contacts);
        String name = null;
        while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equals("region")) {
                if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type").equalsIgnoreCase("continent")) {
                name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                worldRegion.setRegionName(name);
                worldRegionList.add(worldRegion);
                }
            }
            parser.next();
            WorldRegionsAdapter adapter = new 
            WorldRegionsAdapter(this,worldRegionList);
             rvWorldRegions.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't help. The adapter in recyclerview show just one element.